# Override devise helper methods with token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api

I want to override current_user and authenticate_user methods given by devise. I found this code:

**ApplicationHelper**

```
def devise_authenticate_user
  @devise_authenticate_user = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
end

def authenticate_user!
  if is_sandbox?
    return true
  else
    devise_authenticate_user
  end
end
```

It's not working. For example my user show method returns a 401 like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :update_news]

  def index
    if current_user
      render json: {users: User.first}.to_json, success: 200
    else
      send_error('Unauthorized', 401)
    end
  end

end
```

I think it's because I am using the gem devise_token_auth.

Comment: Since, you are calling `authenticate_user!` method in controller. So, you need to define this method in `application_contoller` instead of `application_helper`

Comment: I get the same behaviour: a 401 returned

Comment: One more thing, you are calling `before_action` filter for only `show` and `update_news` actions. While you are getting error on `index` action.